# Is it possible to avoid duplicate of equal arg-name and var-name in method call?

Tags: python, syntax, syntactic-sugar

It it possible to replace

```py
veryLongOption = ...
...    
bar(arg1, arg2, veryLongOption = veryLongOption, anotherVeryLongOption = anotherVeryLongOption, more = more)
```

with something like this?

```py
bar(arg1, arg2, =veryLongOption, =anotherVeryLongOption, =more)
```

**Note:** the question was clarified, the first answer was to the first form of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this for example:

```
def bar(x, y, a, b, c):
    print(x, y, a, b, c)

arg1 = 1
arg2 = 2
def foo(*args):
    bar(arg1, arg2, *args)

foo(3,4,5)
```

Comment: And if I need to pass, for example, only two arguments out of three or `a,b,c` is not foo-arguments but local variables?

Comment: First I'm not sure why you are not happy with  `bar(arg1, arg2, a = a, b = b, c = c)` in the first place... And then I'm very unclear with what your end goal is. Are you giving us an XY problem here?

Comment: I'm not happy how it looks with long named arguments: `foo(myVeryLongOption = myVeryLongOption, myOtherLongOption = myOtherLongOption)`.

Comment: Ok. I had an assumption that there is a simple solution and I just cannot find it.